# Inserting values from JavaScript directly into MySQL database

Tags: javascript, mysql, insert, geolocation

I'm using this JS function to grab visitor geolocation and show it on the page. This works great.

```
        function onGeoSuccess(location) {
        console.log(location);
        var strLocation = '<b>Latitude:</b> ' + location.coords.latitude + '<br />' +
                        '<b>Longitude:</b> ' + location.coords.longitude + '<br />' +
                        '<b>City:</b> ' + location.address.city + '<br />' +
                        '<b>Country:</b> ' + location.address.country + '<br />' +
                        '<b>Country Code:</b> ' + location.address.countryCode + '<br />' +
                        '<b>Region:</b> ' + location.address.region + '<br />' +
                        '<b>Accuracy:</b> ' + location.coords.accuracy + '<br />' +
                        '<br />'
        document.getElementById('geofound').innerHTML = strLocation;
    }
//The callback function executed when the location could not be fetched.
function onGeoError(error) {
    console.log(error);
}

window.onload = function () {
    //geolocator.locateByIP(onGeoSuccess, onGeoError, 2, 'map-canvas');
    var html5Options = { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 6000, maximumAge: 0 };
    geolocator.locate(onGeoSuccess, onGeoError, true, html5Options, 'geo-details');
};
```

Now I would like to save this information into a MySQL database upon each call. Something like:

```
var strLocation = '$addtodb = "mysql_query('INSERT INTO gpsdb (lat, lon, city, country, code, region, accuracy) values (location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude, ...))"'
```

but I don't think this is the correct way to do so. What would be the correct way to enter info into a database directly from JS? I do not need to echo the info as it is doing now in JS, I would rather pull that from the DB once it is entered there. The JS would be used only to insert into DB.

Answer (score 0):

you would need to use an ajax call  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ to your server-side language to then insert the information into the database

e.g

post to database

```
function insertIntoDatabase(location){
 $.ajax({
   url: 'serversideurl',
   type : "POST",       
   data: location,       
   success: function(response) {
    // after success from server show the location on screen?
    document.getElementById('geofound').innerHTML = response.location;
    }
 });

}
```

then inside the server you can parse the object, or have this done by the client before it is sent as data. and run the mysql_query

Comment: Oh ok. So the URL would be a PHP that gets the data from the URL and enters those into the DB, correct? How would I format the lat, lon, etc. strings into the 'serversideurl'?
`url: 'www.foo.com/insert.php?lat=' + location.coords.latitude + '?lon='  + location.coords.longitude + 'etc...',`

Comment: you could change the url to `www.foo.com/insert.php` and the type to a `GET` and change the data to something like: `data: {
     longitude: location.coords.longitude,
     city: location.address.city,
     countrycode: location.address.countryCode,
     region: location.address.region,
     accuracy: location.coords.accuracy
   }` then on the php side you can use commands like `$_GET['city']`